# sort multiples ranges with loop vba

Tags: vba

I have 65 ranges in colums next to each other. The first range is "D39:D122", the next range is "E39:E122"... the last range is "BP39:BP122".

It's possible that all 65 ranges are filed with data, but it is also possible that only 10 ranges are filled with data.I already managed that if there are 10 ranges filled with data, that it is the first 10 ranges that are filled.

The data: it is a list of maximum 84 different cells (from D39 to D122), sometimes only 15 cells are filled with data, sometimes 24, sometimes nothing.

The question: how can a sort each range in ascending order using a loop.

Example

```
        D           E           F       etc... BP
39    ID0077      ID0325     ID0037
40    ID0134      ID0704     ID0206
41    ID0001      ID0011     ID0042
42    ID3481      ID2005     ID0215
43    ID0280      etc..      ID0005
      etc...                 ID0015
                             ID0328
                             ID0712
                             ID0332
                             ID0713
                             etc...
```

Second question: there is a second and a third range like this:the second range from (D126:D209) till (BP126:BP209), the third range from (D299:D303) till (BP299:303). How can I loop through this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Offset to loop through the columns and the worksheet's COUNTA function to make sure there is something to sort. Blank cell will simply be pushed to the bottom.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sort65()
    Dim i As Long

    'define the worksheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        'loop through 65 columns
        For i = 0 To 64

            'offset original by the loop increment
            With .Range("D39:D122").Offset(0, i)

                'make sure there is something to sort
                If Application.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then

                    'sort ascending with no header
                    .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

                End If

            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your quick solution, it does exactly what i want and very fast!

Answer (score 1):

The following sub sorts every column starting from the **4th** column ("D"), stored in variable `FCol` until the last column found in the specified worksheet, `LCol`.

It determines the last filled row in the column, and then sorts the cells starting from the first row (39) until the last row.

If the first row is dynamic, or if you need to change it in the future, you just have to change the `FRow` variable.

```
Sub sortcols()

Dim FRow as Long, FCol as Long, LRow as Long, LCol as Long, i As Long

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)

    FRow = 39
    FCol = 4 'column "D"
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = FCol to LCol

        'Determine the last filled row in the column (starting from the top)
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlDown).Row

        'Sort the cells on the condition that there is data present  
        With .Range(.Cells(FRow, i), .Cells(LRow, i))
            If Not LRow = 1 Then .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With  

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, i changed de two REF's into the name of the workbook en worksheet, but even then... it says that there aren't variables declared... am i doing something wrong here? Thank you anyways for looking into it!

Comment: Are you using Option Explicit? I have edited my code. On what line is the code breaking? If you are using the wb/ws name, have you quoted them (`Sheets("Name")`)?